# GraphicsMagick: issues resizing the output after composition

Tags: graphicsmagick

I’m hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I’ve been trying to use GraphicsMagick to composite three images with a small tweak to one of the colours as well.

The first two images are the same size and are positioned at 0, 0. The third image is smaller, a “design” image and I’ve offset this using –page 320,300.

Everything seems fine up to mosaic.

When I do the resize I would have hoped after the mosaic for the whole image to be resized as one but instead it apples the resize to each of the layers, leaving the third image resized incorrectly.

Is there a way I can solve the resize to work here?

Here is the command I am using:

```
gm convert -background transparent background.png -compose multiply -fill "#FFCCAA" \
    -opaque "#FFFFFF" foreground.png -page +320+300 design.png -mosaic \
    -resize 300x300 result.png
```

Added example of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJZlE.jpg

Comment: Not near a computer, but try `-flatten` before `-resize`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I put this right before the –resize parameter and the only difference is the background becomes black rather than transparent. http://imgur.com/a/creAA

Comment: Just had another look - if you use `-compose multiply`, you would normally issue `-composite` after each additional image, and use `-geometry +320+300` rather than `-page` for positioning.

Comment: @MarkSetchell again thanks for the suggestions. I switched `-page` to `-geometry` but `–composite` is an unrecognised option I'm being told. As a test I stripped it right back to: `gm convert bg.png -geometry +320+300 design.png -mosaic -resize 300x300 result.png` the resize problem remains. Using `–flatten` crops the image to the size of the first image. Is it because I’m using convert? I added a couple of images to that imgur link that might help.

Comment: I'll check it in the morning...

Comment: Mmmm, can't find anything that makes it work with GraphicsMagick. With ImageMagick it is straightforward... `convert -background none a.png -compose multiply b.png -page +50+150 c.png -mosaic -resize 800x800 result.png`

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes it did - I took a proper look last night. I replaced the `-geometry +320+300 design.png` with `-draw "image multiply 320,200 600,600 design.png"`. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but it may be what you seek. Start with `a.png` and `b.png` which are both 300x300 and `c.png` which is 100x100.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now composite `b` onto `a` and resize `c` and composite and resize the result:

```
gm convert a.png -draw "image multiply 0,0 0,0 b.png" -draw "image multiply 100,150 30,30 c.png" -resize 800x300! result.png
```

[image]